# Confirm successful login

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The code i have so far inputs the users username and pas that they inputted into 2 textboxes. Next the user hits login and it submits the info. Here is where i have a problem. Some users are already logged in when they get to the site, this is a problem because i need to make sure they are logging in correctly. Here comes another problem, lets say they log in correctly, how can i know that the login was successful?

Simplified:

1) How can i find out if the user is already logged in so i can log them out.

2) If they are not logged in, and they log in successfully. how can i confirm that?

If there is any other way to login without web browsers, please let me know. I know it seems like im asking for a lot but i really need this code. Thank you very much in advance and i hope the amazing coders ad stackoverflow can help me :)

```
'Code to enter the user and pass into the webpage
 WebBrowser1.document.GetElementById("Username").InnerText = TextBox1.Text

 WebBrowser1.document.GetElementById("Password").InnerText = TextBox2.Text


'Code to click login on the webpage
 WebBrowser1.document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: There are some key details missing. Is your application a WinForm/WPF app that is hosting a WebBrowser? Is it a jQuery module? Something else?

Comment: Please put tags in the tags section and not the title.

Comment: My application is a just a plain windows form application. It has 2 textboxes (User and Pass) and a button to login with. The app uses the webbrowser control to open up the site and log in. I just need to confirm that the user has logged in successfully and that they were not already logged in when they opened up the app. Its very simple atm and im not an expert at coding so i dont know what a jQuery module is. Im making this app for a site so the user can easily log in and make posts and such without having to go into chrome or mozilla or anything. Its like an AIO for a forum.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could confirm that the user was logged in:

- The website or service has an API you can interface with Visual Basic .NET.
- Parsing the output with a DOM parser and looking for common login success message.
- Tracking cookie data for a common login success cookie.

However, all but the first ones rely on hacks and might not be reliable. More importantly, none are easy for a beginner programmer.

Perhaps you could rethink your idea or design: why do you need to know in VB that the user is connected on a website? Isn't the website self-sufficient at handling its connections? If it is your website, couldn't you make your server send you specific login status information on request?

Comment: Its not my website so i cant get the requests. Im not really a beginner, i can code intermediate programs. I've coded programs like this before but sadly, that was a while ago and i annually format my computer, so i lost those files. I tried logging into the site using HttpWebRequest but it wouldnt work. The site kept returning the same message. (Please enter a username and password) Meaning it sent the request but not the credentials.I even had a cookiecontainer ready so i could include the "Remember Me" function. Lazlo,if you are familiar with HttpWebRequest,could you help me out with this?